# Is it possible that a path $a$ is not homotopic to the constant path?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, path-connected

Is my argument correct?

Aim:

Let $X$ be a conected by paths set and $a:[0,1]\to X$ a path. So, $a\simeq c_a$, where $c_a(s)\equiv a(0)$ is the constant path based on $a(0)$.

I think this is trivial, because as $ X $ is connected, using a free homotopy $ H (a, t) = a_t $, where $ a_t (s) = a (ts) $ we deform $ a $ in order to obtain $ a \simeq c_a $.

## Is it correct? Thank you so much.

*edit* $\simeq$ is the free homotopy

Comment: You are technically correct, which is the best form of correct. The map $a$ and the constant map with value $a(0)$ are homotopic by the homotopy you specify

Comment: It is actually very important that all paths are homotopic to a constant map if we allow one endpoint to vary. This comes up a lot when studying loop spaces and fibrations.

Comment: How about a case where the path is a "small" circle on tours? I do not see how you can shrink it to a point ...

Comment: @Salcio, by shrink it always a little bit more, as if the string is always shorter, what do you thin?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you!

Comment: @ConnorMalin  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. In fact, if $Y$ is any contractible space (as $I = [0,1]$) and $f  : Y \to X$ is any map to some space $X$ (**no** assumptions on $X$!), then $f$ is homotopic to a constant map. To see this, let $x_0 \in f(Y)$. Choose $y_0 \in Y$ such that $f(y_0) = x_0$. Since $Y$ is contractible, there exists a homotopy $H : Y \times I \to Y$ such that $H(y,0) = y$ and $H(y,1) = y_0$ for all $y \in Y$. Then $G = f \circ H : Y \times I \to X$ is a homotopy such that $G(y,0) = f(y)$ and $G(y,1) = x_0$ for all $y$.

Note that if we assume $X$ to be path connected, then $f$ is homotopic to *each* constant map $Y \to X$.

Let us emphasize that for $Y = I$ we cannot expect that the homotopy keeps fixed both endpoints $0, 1$ of $I$. This may confuse some readers because they misinterpret the word "homotopy" as "homotopy of paths" which by definition keeps endpoints fixed. However, here we deal with *free homotopies*. The best what can be achieved *in general* is that our homotopy keeps fixed a single point of $I$, for example $0$. Also note that that only closed paths have the chance that there exists a homotopy of paths to a constant path.

Comment: Thank you so much